# Is there anyway to match answers and questions in String array

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

I am trying to code a word game. There are questions which is shown randomly and user try to answer right.

I matched questions and answers with switch case but I can't check if it is right or not because I can't figure out how can I find words in String array. Also, there is an error in the switch-case because of the method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Random;

public class Odev {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the 1 for answer or 2 for requesting a letter.");


    int first= input.nextInt();
    String[] question = new String[9];
    String [] answer=new String[9];
    question=array(question);
    answer=array2(answer);
    Random b= new Random();
    int randomNumber=b.nextInt(question.length);


    if(first==1) {
        System.out.println(question[randomNumber]);

        System.out.println(randomNumber);
        String a1=input.next();
        switch (randomNumber) {
        case 0: equalM(a1, answer[0]);

        break;
        case 1: equalM(a1, answer[1]);

        break;
        case 2:equalM(a1, answer[2]);

        break;
        case 3:equalM(a1, answer[3]);

        break;
        case 4:equalM(a1, answer[4]);

        break;
        case 5:equalM(a1, answer[5]);

        break;
        case 6:equalM(a1, answer[6]);

        break;
        case 7:equalM(a1, answer[7]);

        break;
        case 8:equalM(a1, answer[8]);
        break;
        }
    }


}

public static String [] array(String [] question) {
    question[0]="A beverage which is white and generally consumed in mornings";
    question[1]="The natural satellite of earth";
    question[2]="An adjective which describes people who have not adequate money";
    question[3]="A furniture sit around for eating or studying";
    question[4]="A group that consists a lot of soldier";
    question[5]="A fruit which can be red, yellow and green";
    question[6]="A tool for writing which consists graphite";
    question[7]="A beverage which is consumed by people who need caffeine ";
    question[8]="A term which is stand for the smallest group of the    society  ";
    return question;        
}

public static String [] array2(String [] answer) {  
    answer[0]="milk";
    answer[1]="moon";
    answer[2]="poor";
    answer[3]="table";
    answer[4]="army";
    answer[5]="apple";
    answer[6]="pencil";
    answer[7]="coffee";
    answer[8]="family";
    return answer;
}

public static String[] equalM(String a1, String[] answer) {
     for (int i=0; i<answer.length; i++) {
         if(a1.equals(answer[i])) {
             System.out.println("Correct you gained 500 points");
         } else 
             System.out.println("Wrong.You lost 500 points");
     }
     return answer;
}

}
```

Comment: That switch is useless. Your code is equivalent to `equalM(a1, answer[randomNumber]);` - as for your `equalM` method itself; check **all** of the answers before declaring the answer wrong (or right). As is, you check each answer (and report the results) against **all** of the answers. That's not right. You should probably pass in the question number too... otherwise, the wrong answer in the right way is counted as correct. On reflection, you just want `a1.equals(answer[randomNumber])`

Comment: I know it is useless but I can not do answers string thing and I can not figure out. So, I came here to find anyone that can help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hashmap to do this easily, but if you want to stick with arrays, you could print out all the answer choices along with their index number, and then read in the number the user types in for the correct answer. You then just have to check if that number is equal to the random number used to generate the question.